# OpenLayers print Logo

Tags: openlayers-2, export, printing

I added a logo image for the map in this way:

```
<div id="map" class="map sidebar-map">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" title="Click to toggle controls" (click)="toggleControlsVisibility()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used both  ol-ext/control/Print and html2canvas to print the map, but neither one inlcudes the Logo. Is there any posibility to add Logo as a map Control or to include it into the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I created my custom control that I added to the map.

```
export class LogoControl extends Control {

 private controlsVisible: boolean;
 private utilService: any;
 private elemRef: any;

 constructor(opt_options) {
  const options = opt_options || {};

  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.id = "logo";
  element.className = 'ol-unselectable ol-control';
  element.style.position = "absolute";
  element.style.bottom = "52px";
  element.style.left = "62px";
  ....
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "assets/img/logo.png";
  img.style.maxWidth = "168px";
  img.style.maxHeight = "60px";
  element.appendChild(img);

  super({
   element: element,
   target: options.target,
  });
 }
}
```

html2canvas prints controls from the map.